# Unit-testing a periodic coroutine with mock time

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, asynchronous, tornado

I'm using Tornado as a coroutine engine for a periodic process, where the repeating coroutine calls `ioloop.call_later()` on itself at the end of each execution. I'm now trying to drive this with unit tests (using Tornado's gen.test) where I'm mocking the ioloop's time with a local variable t:
`DUT.ioloop.time = mock.Mock(side_effect= lambda: t)`
*(DUT <==> Device Under Test)*
Then in the test, I manually increment t, and `yield gen.moment` to kick the ioloop. The idea is to trigger the repeating coroutine after various intervals so I can verify its behaviour.
But the coroutine doesn't always trigger - or perhaps it yields back to the testing code before completing execution, causing failures. 
I think should be using `stop()` and `wait()` to synchronise the test code, but I can't see concretely how to use them in this situation. And how does this whole testing strategy work if the DUT runs in its own ioloop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, using `yield gen.moment` to trigger specific events is dicey; there are no guarantees about how many "moments" you must wait, or in what order the triggered events occur. It's better to make sure that the function being tested has some effect that can be asynchronously waited for (if it doesn't have such an effect naturally, you can use a `tornado.locks.Condition`).

There are also subtleties to patching `IOLoop.time`. I think it will work with the default Tornado IOLoops (where it is possible without the use of `mock`: pass a `time_func` argument when constructing the loop), but it won't have the desired effect with e.g. `AsyncIOLoop`.

I don't think you want to use `AsyncTestCase.stop` and `.wait`, but it's not clear how your test is set up.

Comment: Thanks Ben! My function under test can send a blinker.signal when it runs; That should help synchronise the tests and may also be useful in other ways.