# Mocking the Internal Clock of Asyncio Event Loop

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

We are using `asyncio.get_event_loop()` as a scheduler in a real-time message driven environment.

For (back)testing purposes we replay the time-stamped messages and regard their time-stamp as the simulated/synthetic/mock time.
This only works if we replace the internal clock of the event loop. How can we do this?

Note that Python 3.6.6, BaseEventLoop implements

```
def time(self):
    return time.monotonic()
```

and we'd like to have

```
def time(self):
    return current_message.timestamp
```

Possible solutions, all flawed:

1. Subclass AbstractEventLoop? -> Not really, as AbstractEventLoop is pretty naked.
2. Subclass BaseEventLoop? -> Docs state: It should not be used directly; use AbstractEventLoop instead.
3. Monkey patch asyncio.get_event_loop().time()? -> May work, but may break anytime.
4. Monkey patch time.monotonic()? Worse than (3).
5. Try to understand asyncio.test_utils.TestLoop? -> Internal, not documented.
6. Kick asyncio altogether?

Related: [Unit-testing a periodic coroutine with mock time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33940518/unit-testing-a-periodic-coroutine-with-mock-time)

Note: `sched.scheduler()` can be injected with a synthetic time (!), but it does blocking sleeps.

Comment: Monkey-patching `BaseEventLoop.time` seems like the obvious choice. It's technically true that it "may break anytime", if it does indeed happen, it will only break tests, and you will have the option to switch to another strategy. With modern testing frameworks such as `py.test` it is trivial to perform the monkey patch for only a localized section of code and clean up immediately afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

It's unfortunate that—even as of this writing—`asyncio` apparently lacks decent abstractions to allow deterministic advancement of clocks in testing like [Twisted has](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/development/policy/test-standard.html#real-time).

What about replacing `loop` itself? Does [`async-solipsism`](https://pypi.org/project/async-solipsism/) work for your use case? (It has some [limitations](https://github.com/bmerry/async-solipsism#limitations) that may not make sense in your world.)

From the [README](https://github.com/bmerry/async-solipsism/blob/master/README.md):

> #### Clock
>
> A very handy feature is that time runs infinitely fast! What's more, time
> advances only when explicitly waiting. For example, this code will print out
> two times that are exactly 60s apart, and will take negligible real time to
> run:
>
> ```
> print(loop.time())
> await asyncio.sleep(60)
> print(loop.time())
> ```
>
> This also provides a handy way to ensure that all pending callbacks have a
> chance to run: just sleep for a second.
>
> The simulated clock has microsecond resolution, independent of whatever
> resolution the system clock has. This helps ensure that tests behave the same
> across operating systems.
>
> Sometimes buggy code or a buggy test will await an event that will never
> happen. For example, it might wait for data to arrive on a socket, but forget
> to insert data into the other end. If async-solipsism detects that it will
> never wake up again, it will raise a `SleepForeverError` rather than leaving
> your test to hang.
>
> …
>
> #### Integration with pytest-asyncio
>
> async-solipsism and pytest-asyncio complement each other well: just write a
> custom `event_loop` fixture in your test file or `conftest.py` and it will
> override the default provided by pytest-asyncio:
>
> ```
> @pytest.fixture
> def event_loop():
>     loop = async_solipsism.EventLoop()
>     yield loop
>     loop.close()
> ```

In the alternative, could you use [`asynctest`](https://asynctest.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)'s [`ClockedTestCase`](https://asynctest.readthedocs.io/en/latest/asynctest.case.html#asynctest.ClockedTestCase)? (See the [tutorial](https://asynctest.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/tutorial/clock.py.html).) That framework (unfortunately) requires deriving from that base class, which may not be an option for you. *UPDATE: I was also recently made aware of `aiotools`' [`VirtualClock`](https://aiotools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aiotools.timer.html#aiotools.timer.VirtualClock), which may be helpful.*

Comment: For the project that sparked the question, we gave up on asyncio and used old style threading.

Answer (score 0):

This is a **no**-answer to my question. I tried to monkey-patch BaseEventLoop.time, see code below. However the result is not what we had in mind. The `some_callback` is run at time 2, not at time 1.5:

```
0: Message(timestamp=0, msg='Beautiful is better than ugly.')
1: Message(timestamp=1, msg='Explicit is better than implicit.')
2: some_callback
2: Message(timestamp=2, msg='Simple is better than complex.')
3: Message(timestamp=3, msg='Complex is better than complicated.')
```

Probably we will have to mess around with `asyncio.sleep` to fix, but that's too freaky. Conclusion so far: **Can't do it with asyncio**. Here's the code:

```
import asyncio
from typing import Iterator
import dataclasses


@dataclasses.dataclass
class Message:
    timestamp: float
    msg: str


def some_callback():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    print(f'{loop.time()}: some_callback')


def zen_generator() -> Iterator[Message]:
    from this import d, s
    lines = ''.join([d.get(c, c) for c in s]).splitlines()[2:6]

    for timestamp, msg in enumerate(lines):
        yield Message(timestamp, msg)


def loop_pulse(head_message: Message, tail_messages: Iterator[Message]):
    """Self-scheduling callback driving the loop's internal clock"""
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    print(f'{loop.time()}: {head_message}')

    try:
        head_message = next(tail_messages)
    except StopIteration:
        loop.stop()
        return

    # Monkey-patch
    loop.time = lambda: head_message.timestamp
    loop.call_at(head_message.timestamp, lambda: loop_pulse(head_message, tail_messages))


def main():
    messages = zen_generator()
    head_message = next(messages)

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.time = lambda: head_message.timestamp
    loop_pulse(head_message, messages)
    loop.call_at(loop.time() + .5, some_callback)
    loop.run_forever()


main()
```